# Query entities by specifying a list of values in GAE Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

In my Datastore, I would like to query some entities by specifying as Filter the values of the same property.
For instance I have the Entity named Foo defined as follows:

`type Foo struct {
  Id        int64
  Name      string
  CreatorId int64
}`

And I want to retrieve all the Foo entities which have 1, 5, 23 as CreatorId. So I define the following query:

`q := datastore.NewQuery("Foo").Filter("CreatorId =", 1).Filter("CreatorId =", 5).Filter("CreatorId =", 23)`

But zero entity has been fetched. I looked into the documentation (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference) but it is not explained how to achieve this kind of query.

Some help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't that query return only entities where the CreatorId is 1, 5, AND 23? I would assume that's not possible, depending on your data model (so zero is records is what I'd expect).

Comment: You need to use an 'In Query'. Not sure the syntax in Go, but Python is .filter('CreatorID IN', [1, 5, 23]). These are expensive though - the more items you have in your list, the more queries it performs under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Java and Python allow you to run a query for a value in a collection (IN query). Under the surface, however, this query is executed as a series of EQUALS queries. It's a little less code, but no difference performance-wise, than to run regular EQUALS query in a loop.

Comment: That's what I'm doing by using Filters in cascade. I have the feeling that it is similar to an AND operation (1 AND 5 AND 23 = 0 result).

Comment: You should run 3 separate queries to get all of these entities.

Comment: IN queries are not available with Go. I will keep the 3 separate queries method.